# How to select x value of max y in R

Tags: r, max, markdown

I have a table with an x and y value as follows:;

```
cbm <- captialbikedata %>%
    group_by(hr) %>%
    summarize(users = sum(registered))
```

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 |
| 2 | 45 |

in this case how would I select 2? (I want to select the x value with the highest y value and then put it in a red file)

Comment: Like this: `cbm$x[max(cbm$y)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `slice_max`

```
library(dplyr)
red <- cbm %>%
    ungroup %>%
    slice_max(y) %>%
    pull(x)
```

Comment: with this I get the result of both x and y (2 and 45 in my example) am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Christian you want only `x`?

Comment: @Christian updated the post